# How to keep PHP script running until it finishes?

Tags: php, memory, rss

I have a script which looks for specific words in environmental news articles. It can process one article, and then maybe five more and then (NO DATA RECEIVED) However, I have to cycle through about 30 RSS Feeds which contain 10 articles each, once per week.

Is there a more robust solution? Or some way to have it process a few and then restart itself?

```
my colleague suggested I explain what happens in the script.
the script loads RSS Feeds from a list. one by one.
it uses magpie_debug to obtain links, title, dates. 
if the date is less than 60 minutes ago, (fresh article) 
it pulls the plaintext (simple_DOM) attaches POS tags using brill tagger
splits text into sentences.
builds arrays of capitalized nouns, matches them twelve different word banks
including a large database of chemicals, companies etc. and generates an
algorithm of 'total environmental impact' for each sentence.
moves to next sentence in article until completed. 
each article takes about 10 seconds to process. 
Moves to the next article. Until all articles processed.
Moves to next feed until all feeds processed.
```

I can grab the plaintext of all articles/feeds no problem, but once I throw in the processing, the capability drops dramatically. I get a NO DATA RECEIVED after about four articles.

Comment: maybe you can show us some code?

Comment: If your PHP process is timing out, you can use `set_time_limit(0)`.

Comment: you can maybe have it process one article, do something with it, then start another. sounds like you are having timeouts of some sort.

Comment: the code is vast - but the above description gives you an idea what happens memory-wise.

Comment: Why is this complex code running inside a web server? It sounds like a job for a daemon. Set up a web frontend to a long-running process, don't put the massive job inside the web engine.

Comment: sounds like you should set up a cron job for this. this way your script will run automatically each week. would have to see code to figure out how to fix your memory problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for based on the title of your question:

```
<?php
//set the time limit to infinite
set_time_limit(0);

//do more stuff
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the time limit code, but it didn't change much - still timing out NO DATA. We got some input from a PHP, says between Simple_DOM and Brill Tagger, the memory is pushed to the max.

Comment: ah. ok. if you want to post some of the processing code we can probably reduce memory usage as well.